# Angular 2 view not updating after behaviourSubject updates

Tags: angular, view

I have a component which is a child of the root, the component has 1 property which gets updated when the behaviourSubject changes. The view loops through this property displaying the results on the page.

The problem is that the component does not show the list if I use this.changeDetector.detectChanges(). If I remove this line I can see the list but the view does not change when I change the sort order of the list.

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
import {MapLocation} from "../models/location";
import {MapStoreService} from "../store/location.store";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-location-list',
  templateUrl: './location-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./location-list.component.css']
})
export class LocationListComponent implements OnInit {
  private locationList: MapLocation[];

  constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef,private     mapStoreService: MapStoreService) {
    this.mapStoreService.publicLocationList.subscribe(objList => {
      this.locationList = objList;
      this.triggerChanges();
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  triggerChanges(){
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
  }

}
```

A map service changes the sort order which then updates the store.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The view is a simple list <div *ngFor="let loc of locationList">{{loc.locName}}</div>

Comment: Can you create plunker?